# Is there a way to temporarily disable hosts and flush the DNS?

Tags: networking, dns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I flush the DNS Cache?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/how-can-i-flush-the-dns-cache)

In order to visite some websites, i modified the `hosts` in the `system/etc/hosts`. But sometimes, the IP i write in the `hosts` file maybe invalid, but i don't want to remove it and restart the android phone again.

So how can i temporarily disable the hosts and reflush the DNS. Is there an app, or any other advices will be very appreciated.