# DNS queries are cached permanently, how to reliably clear DNS cache on Android 7+?

Tags: 7.0-nougat, networking, cache, dns

Is there a reliable, reproducible way to clear DNS cache on Android Nougat 7.0?

I know there is at least [one other question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12962/how-can-i-flush-the-dns-cache) like this but that one was from 8 years ago and I hope I can ask again and see what people are doing these days.

To explain a bit more my setup:

I am testing a simple web page loading in Chrome browser with Wireshark packet capture to see the DNS requests. I am also running `dnsmasq` on my LAN and have mapped my webpages name: `mymovies` to the correct IP address of the machine on my LAN that the web server is on. So `http://mymovies` should work and it does load.

The DNS lookups initially start with the DHCP server appending the DNS suffix (`.home`) so in the packet trace I see a DNS request for `mymovies.home` which fails because I don't have an IP address mapping for that in `dnsmasq.conf`. So a second DNS lookup for just `mymovies` appears and is successful.

Mostly I find that subsequent DNS lookups are always just for `mymovies` and never again for `mymovies.home` no matter what I try to clear the DNS cache:

[image]

I am testing over WiFi with a Moto G5 running Android 7.0 and it is rooted so I can run commands from within `adb shell` to the OS.

I have tried lots of things like:

1. Closing down Chrome browser and starting it up again.
2. `chrome://net-internals/#dns` to clear host cache and flushing the sockets too
3. Settings > Apps > Chrome > Storage > Clear Cache
4. `ndc resolver clearnetdns wlan0`

The only thing that seemed to work for me was turning the phone off and on again. After restart I opened `http://mymovies` in Chrome on the phone. The page loaded and in the Wireshark trace I see the first DNS request for `mymovies.home` which fails as usual followed by a DNS request for `mymovies` that succeeds. I then closed down that tab and opened a new one and loaded the page again.. I did this twice. Each time now I see a dns request for `mymovies` only.. it doesn't even try `mymovies.home`.

I restarted `dnsmasq` server and the first DNS lookup after that was for `mymovies.home` followed by a lookup for `mymovies`. But since then the DNS lookups are now only ever for `mymovies`. This is despite restarting the `dnsmasq` server a few times and trying the four so-called DNS cache clearing steps listed above.

But to confuse the matters, I tried the trick of switching into and back out of Airplane Mode. Now when I load my little test web page a few times it doesn't seem to cache at all anymore? Loading the webpage always initially gives a DNS look up for `mymovies.home` which fails then a lookup for `mymovies` that succeeds. Even after restarting the phone the DNS lookups have now stopped caching completely and it firstly tries `mymovies.home` every time!

I think this caching behavior is normal and expected but I'd just like a way to clear that cache so it goes back to trying `mymovies.home` without me having to restart the phone.

I'm not sure if the IPv6 has anything to do with things? In my router I have specified the IP address of the Raspberry Pi on my LAN that `dnsmasq` is running on so the router directs DNS requests to it.

I don't want the page to stop caching OR to always cache. I just want to be able to clear the DNS cache in a predictable manner so I can make the DNS request for `mymovies.home` appear once followed by the expected DNS caching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### HOW DNS QUERY AND CACHING WORKS?

> Mostly I find that subsequent DNS lookups are always just for `mymovies` and never again for `mymovies.home`

---

NOTE: Just to make sure, check that `.home` search domain is set:

```
~$ dumpsys netd | grep 'search domains:'
        search domains: home
```

---

This behavior is due to [Negative DNS Caching](https://myitpath.blogspot.com/2011/12/dns-negative-caching.html). The question is not explicitly about Android but more about the understanding of how DNS works. In short:

- When you type `mymovies` in a web browser (assuming that the browser doesn't cache DNS), Android's DNS resolver checks domain <--> IP mapping in local cache (`netd`) and `/etc/hosts`. Then it makes a query (for [`A` record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.4.1)) to the IP address of DNS server it received from DHCP (or you set manually), which is `dnsmasq` in your case. As standard is to append suffix first, so `mymovies.home` is queried first. See details in [How does Android OS do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526)
- `dnsmasq` checks static mapping in `hosts` and `dnsmasq.conf` file. If no result found, it forwards query to upstream DNS server, whatever configured in `dnsmasq.conf` or `/etc/resolv.conf` (or whatever mechanism the system uses) - say `1.1.1.1`.
- After receiving a successful or failed response, `dnsmasq` answers the client (Android phone) along with Time To Live (TTL) value.
- Neither `dnsmasq` nor `1.1.1.1` is able to resolve `mymovies.home` because `.home` is not a known Top Level [Domain Name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_name) (TLD) to any authoritative server. So a [`NXDOMAIN`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8020#section-1) response (*"which means that the queried domain name does not exist in the DNS"*) is returned by [root server](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) (or some intermediate recursive caching server). Response includes an [`SOA` record](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.3.13) with high TTL (and [`SOA.MINIMUM` field](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2308#section-5)) value - say 5 hours.
- `dnsmasq` caches the `NXDOMAIN` response with 5 hours expiry and forwards the same to Android.
- Android's resolver caches the same for 5 hours, but that time may get doubled in some situations; see some explanation [here](https://github.com/coredns/coredns/issues/2158). Also [How long does negative DNS caching typically last?](https://serverfault.com/q/426807/452872).
- Android's resolver makes another query for (`A` RR of) `mymovies`, which succeeds at `dnsmasq` and is returned with a smaller TTL which must be `0` in your case (see option `--local-ttl` in [`dnsmasq` man](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html)).

So Android's resolver will make next query for `mymovies.home` after 5 hours, and for `mymovies` after 0 seconds. If you want that `mymovies.home` should be tried again sooner, define a static mapping, which can possibly be `--address=/mymovies.home/` to get `NXDOMAIN` from `dnsmasq` with no TTL. Or to have some fun, setup [`NXDOMAIN` Redirection](https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00376) locally.

---

### DNS TROUBLESHOOTING:

I'll suggest you to simplify your setup. You don't necessarily need Wireshark, just use `--log-queries` option to see how `dnsmasq` responds to queries. Also once get rid of cache COMPLETELY on Android and DNS server. But note that you may still end up getting a cached response from some recursive non-iterative server, like if your ISP does DNS interception.

> I have tried lots of things like:

2. `chrome://net-internals/#dns` to clear host cache and flushing the sockets too

Clearing browser's DNS cache doesn't clear OS's system-wide cache (maintained by `netd`), though both need to be cleared. Better try testing with some native tool (like `dig` or `nslookup`) which doesn't rely on system's resolver and doesn't do caching itself. On Termux, for instance:

```
~$ dig mymovies @<dnsmasq_IP>
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR
;; ANSWER SECTION:
mymovies.com.       0   IN  A   192.168.1.124
```

```
~$ dig mymovies.home @<dnsmasq_IP>
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN
;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.           10678   IN  SOA a.root-servers.net. nstld.verisign-grs.com. 2020010901 1800 900 604800 86400
```

Note `NOERROR` response and the TTL (`0`) of positive answer, while `NXDOMAIN` response, TTL (`10678`) and `SOA.MINIMUM` (`86400`) of negative answer.

> Even after restarting the phone the DNS lookups have now stopped caching completely and it firstly tries `mymovies.home` every time!

However on the very next query (`dig mymovies.home @<dnsmasq_IP>`), there would be no `AUTHORITY SECTION`. It's because SOA RR (the source of negative TTL) is not cached (as per [RR format](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035#section-3.2.1)): *"SOA records are always distributed with a zero TTL to prohibit caching"*. But `dnsmasq` is doing negative caching (see option `--no-negcache`), so this time it's responding with `NXDOMAIN` from its own cache, **but with no TTL**.

That's why if you clear cache on Android, it then keeps on querying `mymovies` as well as `mymovies.home` because both are not being cached on Android due to zero TTL, unless you restart `dnsmasq` or `10678` seconds pass. To verify, send `SIGUSR1` to `dnsmasq` and see in log the expiry time against `mymovies.home` cache entry. However some other DNS servers may behave differently.

---

### CLEARING DNS CACHE:

> 4. `ndc resolver clearnetdns wlan0`

This command clears DNS server, not DNS cache. See [How to configure DNS properly?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526).

> Is there a reliable, reproducible way to clear DNS cache on Android Nougat 7.0?

Yes, but not a straightforward command-line method. From the perspective of negative caching, we don't have anything like `unbound-control flush_negative` on Android. `ndc resolver flushnet <network_ID>` was [removed in Android 7](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/767cd3fc050503a52bb03ce1ac72dc6ae2788666), though [`flushDnsCache`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/server/ResolverController.cpp#397) still exists. Neither we can call [`_resolv_flush_cache_for_net`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/libc/dns/resolv/res_cache.c#1898) from command-line. Services [`network_management`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/core/java/android/os/INetworkManagementService.aidl) and [`netd_listener`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/server/binder/android/net/metrics/INetdEventListener.aidl) also don't provide any such method.

- However `setResolverConfiguration` (part of `netd` service) [states](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/server/binder/android/net/INetd.aidl#186): *"Flushes the cache as needed (i.e. when the servers ... change)"*. This can also be called using `ndc`:

~$ ndc resolver clearnetdns <network_ID>
~$ ndc resolver setnetdns <network_ID> home <dmsmasq_IP>
```
<sup>* `network_ID` can be obtained using `dumpsys netd | grep Default`</sup>

So the cache should be cleared with DNS server reset. Additionally sending broadcast `android.intent.action.CLEAR_DNS_CACHE` ([`flushVmDnsCache`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/services/core/java/com/android/server/connectivity/DnsManager.java#427)) might also be required to clear [DVM's cache](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/InetAddress#inetaddress-caching) (or kill the apps). A simple explanation can be found [here](http://www.myhowto.org/java/42-understanding-host-name-resolution-and-dns-behavior-in-java/).

But I'm not sure if this method works on all Android releases.

- Turning Wi-Fi OFF and ON (or Airplane Mode) must work as `network_ID` is destroyed and a new one is created.
- Or restart the networking / caching daemon (`netd`). This also restarts dependent services (including `zygote`), so causes a [soft reboot](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/219876/218526) and kills all running apps:

~# setprop ctl.restart netd
```

- There's also a hack to bypass / disable DNS caching entirely using environment variable [`ANDROID_DNS_MODE=local`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/netd/+/refs/tags/android-9.0.0_r1/server/main.cpp#124). But it also disables search domains (`.home` suffix in your case).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103192/discussion-between-irfan-latif-and-flexmcmurphy).

Comment: great explanation. unfortunately I don't have root access. and don't want to as the applications (like banking apps) refuse to work on rooted phones and I don't want 2 devices just because android is rude. anyway: restarting, airplane mode switching networks: my local dns server is listed but don't get a request - frustrating. i begin to hate dns caching especially because there is no easy way for the user to bypass the cache (at least for next request).

Comment: Why do you need a rooted device? // Cache not cleared even after reboot doesn't make much sense. Might be a case of encrypted DNS.