# DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN on one of many

Tags: browser, dns, web-server

I have an issue with one Android device accessing the local web server. We have about ten of the same devices, but one refuses to connect.

It always returns the following error in any of the browsers used on the device: DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN. I have checked the server IP and DNS name settings in local DNS servers, and everything is set as it should be.

I am really puzzled, and do not know where should I start. Even if I enter the IP address directly, it doesn't work and returns the same error.

I suspect there might be something in the device settings, but I can't find what. We tried returning to factory settings, and nothing.

What is the possible cause and how to fix it?

Comment: What "browser" are you talking about? Different browsers can use different DNS implementations (e.g. Firefox). Check the device if it uses private DNS (see Android network settings).

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts. We have [some existing questions mentioning DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN](https://android.stackexchange.com/search?q=DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN). [One of the recent questions](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/226736/44325) has comments for troubleshooting the DNS resolution, you probably want to check it.

Comment: Browser is not the right tool to troubleshoot network issues. Use Termux or ADB shell to find if name resolution works and the host can be pinged. What DNS server is resolving the domain name of your local web server? What's the Android version?

Comment: Thanks for replies. I tried Chrome, SeaMonkey and Samsung browser. The DNS that resolves local server name is local. We have three, two are connected and domain controllers and one separate failback one that has manual setting. Not sure the version, but I updated to the latest available (don't have the device just now). I understand I have to use Termux to see what happens with DNS and will do that. When I enter server IP directly it also gets translated to local DNS name so to me it seems DNS resolution works.

Comment: I installed Termux and checked the ping / nslookup: I can ping the host normally, but when I use nslookup for local names (only on internal network), I get replies from 8.8.8.8 - I checked the DNS settings in the system / WiFi properties, and there it is set OK through DHCP. Is there a setting somewhere else that sets the 8.8.8.8??

Comment: @mrmut please see [How does Android do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526), [How to configure DNS?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526) and [Accessing local computer using hostname](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220876/218526).

Comment: Also [How to make Termius look for hostnames on the local network first?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215879/218526) and [How to ping a local network host by hostname?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/215878/218526)

Comment: Thanks. Will have to dig and test! Will ping back.