# How to troubleshoot DNS not resolved issues?

Tags: networking, internet, dns, android-tv

I can't open Hotstar/Disney+ on my Android phone/ Android TV. Upon investigation, I found out that the webpage hotstar.com is not opening in general on my phone/TV and is throwing an "err::NAME NOT RESOLVED" error. I can open hotstar.com on my laptop using the same network. Since this problem just started abruptly, I don't even know where to look for. Thanks for any suggestions you may provide.

Comment: Start with [`dig`](https://ss64.com/bash/dig.html). See my answers to [How does Android OS do DNS name resolution?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526) and [How to configure DNS on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526) and [How to clear DNS cache on Android?](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220129/218526)

Comment: I did some more investigations and it turns out my ISP is probably spoofing my DNS queries. It works fine if I use a VPN or a private DNS(on my phone, dns.google) or an encrypted DNS (using the app blokada). However, using those is really cumbersome on a frigging TV and I had to sideload those apps. It also shows non-existent domain on nslookup on my desktop. I did factory resets on my TV, it didn't help. I may try changing the DNS manually if I can figure out how to connect to my TV in debugger mode. I can't set up a static ip for my devices either so far.