# Android 11 does not seem to use DNS

Tags: wi-fi, networking, dns

On my Android device, I'm connected to a wifi router which is connected my home network. I tried setting DNS to 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, and other DNSs. If I ping, say, 8.8.4.4, the connection works.

Whatsapp, which seems to be using fixed IP addresses, and doesn't consult DNS, works fine.

But, if in Firefox, I try to any domain name, it doesn't resolve. Neither does any ping to a domain name.

I'm monitoring traffic on the local network with Wireshark to see if any DNS requests come from the phone - no luck...

Anyone has a suggestion how to proceed?

Comment: Are you only looking for UDP DNS traffic or also for DNS over TLS or HTTPS? Android uses such techniques if private DNS is active and as far as I remember Firefox uses it's own DNS resolver settings.

Comment: I have Wireshark monitor _all_ packets. I see, of course the normal TCP and UDP packets, but also ICMP (such as the pings) and others. As other PCs are on the local net, I also see DNS requests from those machines.

Comment: *"I tried setting DNS to 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1, and other DNSs"*. How did you do that?

Comment: @IrfanLatif. Something like: https://gadgets.ndtv.com/mobiles/features/how-to-change-dns-server-on-android-1672117

Comment: You need to do the normal DNS troubleshooting steps. `dig` is a good companion. Some in-depth details, may help in troubleshooting: [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/218209/218526), [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/205740/218526) and [here](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220129/218526).

Comment: Not sure if Firefox for Android is also affected but the desktop version has currently problems with server using HTTP/3 protocol (which cause multiple bugs and lets Firefox run an endless loop). If this also the case for the Android version this problem could cause your problems with Firefox.

Comment: @Robert, Thanks, but I suspect the issue is not Firefox-specific. A simple `ping` to a domain name (instead of an IP) does not seem to call DNS either.

Comment: @IrfanLatif, Thanks for the suggestions - the info was certainly welcome. I think I have a fair understanding of how DNS works. I'm new to Android though, and I see that such obvious tools as `dig`, `nslookup` are not available eg. in `Material-terminal`.  So I thought about sending a 'manual' DNS request using `nc` and `echo` (to eliminate possible firewall problems).