# How to have stable WiFi connection and have autoconnection working?

Tags: wi-fi

I have Motorola G play with Internet & mobile providers: Xfinity & Xfinity Mobile; my Mobile data in Network settings is turned off; also have option "use WiFi when Mobile network is not available" being set to "on".

When I am away of my WiFi router I connect to available not password protected WiFi routers. When connection is lost there's no attempt to reconnect automatically.

Even after the first time manual connection to available WiFi routers the reported problem persists. Also very often attempts of consequent manual connection to those WiFi routers results in getting those WiFi into "saved" state instead of establishing connection, in spite that those WiFi routers being characterized as having "fair" or even "good" signal strength...

Also even when WiFi shows as being connected sometimes there's no connection to websites via browser...

Could someone explain me in details the internals of connection to WiFi: particularly what Wifi server is getting selected for connection and why connection is not getting completed and instead this WiFi server is getting marked as "saved"?

Is connection to WiFi router supported by Android OS or Motorola or by my providers?

So what is wrong and how to fix this problem?

What could be done to have stable wifi connection and to have auto connection working?

PS ChatGPT gave very vague answer re the potential root causes of my problem as follows:

"Network congestion: In areas with many WiFi networks, network congestion can impact connectivity. Try connecting to your router on a less congested WiFi channel.

Battery optimization: Sometimes, aggressive battery optimization settings can interfere with WiFi connections. Check your device's battery or power settings to ensure WiFi isn't being optimized excessively.

App interference: Certain apps or settings might interfere with WiFi. Try booting your phone in Safe Mode and see if the WiFi connection improves. If it does, a third-party app might be causing the issue.

Contact your provider: If the problem persists, you can contact your mobile provider or Motorola's support for further assistance.

The process of connecting to WiFi involves your device's operating system, hardware, and the WiFi router itself. Android's OS, your device, and the router collaborate to establish a connection".

Comment: Android only connects to Wifi networks it knows so for each Wifi you have to connect at least one time manually. That is a security measure as otherwise an attacker could setup a rogue hotspot and all phones would connect to it, which may allow manipulate network traffic or even attack the phone.

Comment: @Robert Even after the first time manual connection to available WiFi routers the reported problem persists. Also very often attempts of consequent manual connection to those WiFi routers results in getting those WiFi into "saved" state instead of establishment connection in spite that those WiFi routers being characterized as having "fair" or even "good" signal strength... So what is wrong and how to fix this problem?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens when you reboot your device OR switch off wifi, turn on airplane mode for a little while a few seconds, turn  wifi on, airplane mode off. This is when you are faced with such a scenario //I vaguely recall reading that this resets connections

Comment: @beeshyams I haven't tried this entire sequence of steps, especially setting airplane mode on. Could someone explain me in details the internals of connection to WiFi: particularly what Wifi server is getting selected for connection and why connection is not getting completed and instead this WiFi   server is getting marked as saved?

Comment: My suggestion was based on [Irfan's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220054/dns-queries-are-cached-permanently-how-to-reliably-clear-dns-cache-on-android-7/220129?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C4.5369#220129) plus personal experience //I am not competent to judge suitability of that approach in your problem

Comment: Is this a new device? I have an older Pixel device (3a xl) that I use as a WiFi only device and in much of the same scenarios with WiFi as you describe, but once I have manually connected to a network, it will ALWAYS reconnect when it is range without issue, I have about 12 open networks and a handful of secure ones saved, whichever one I am in the vicinity of it connects reliably every time. Perhaps this is something you need to open a ticket with Motorola about?

Comment: @acejavelin The reported by me behavior was present for all the time when I had older device -  Motorola 5e and it continues since I replaced it in this spring with the newer device Motorola Gplay... So you think it is Motorola issue rather then Android OS's or my Xfinity and Xfinity Mobile providers? I can't figure out who of them responsible for what in the connecting to WiFi process...

Comment: I can't specifically answer that, but I can tell you my primary device is a Moto Edge Plus 5G (2022) on Android 13 and it does not have the issues you described, nor did it on Android 12.

Comment: @acejavelin If it is not a secret, who is your Mobile phone provider?

Comment: No secret... US Mobile's Warp 5G service, which is an MVNO for Verizon.