# Why do my wifi networks vanish until I turn airplane mode off and on?

Tags: samsung, wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-20

Over the last few weeks, my Samsung Galaxy S20 FE 5G (Android version 13) seems to lose all wifi networks. Going to Wifi settings shows no networks connected or listed at all.

Every other device in the room can see my networks and others. There are no errors reported, and it's not hanging forever. I get a busy indicator for a few seconds, and then it turns off as if the wifi check just didn't return anything.

If I turn on airplane mode, wait a few seconds, and then turn it off again, it can suddenly see all the networks and connects successfully. Then sometime later (I don't know how long but hours, not days), I notice that the phone is using 5G again. If I go back to the Wifi settings, no networks are listed. This happens a few times a day.

I've tried restarting it a number of times and making sure the OS is updated. My wife and son each have an identical S20 and they are not seeing this.

Is this a known problem? Is there a remedy short of a factory reset?

Comment: Toggling airplane mode resets the wifi and that's the reason you can see the networks. I have no idea what is causing that but to rule out a misbehaving app check if it happens in the "safe mode" too and update the question with your findings

Comment: For details on toggling airplane mode and [how it helps](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220129/131553)

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a few things to try.

1. Click on the gear of the connected wifi and flick the `auto connect` switch to on.
2. There could be an app doing it. Look at the permissions of your apps and remove location permission  to drill down to the culprit.
3. There could be a hardware fault.