# How to find the culprit of "no internet connection"?

Tags: samsung, internet, android-13

I have a Samsung Galaxy S22 phone with Android 13. About once or twice a month I'm facing with "no internet connection" issue while using mobile data (not a Wi-Fi). Switching off and on mobile data transfer doesn't help, but turning on Airplane mode and switching it off helps.

The question: how I can be sure is it a phone, or a carrier problem. Is it possible to find the culprit without using a SIM card from another operator?

Comment: [Turning Wi-Fi OFF and ON (or Airplane Mode) must work as network_ID is destroyed and a new one is created](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/220129/131553) // To my understanding, if this works it's got nothing to do with your carrier. But I am no expert. You can maybe add that portion to your question to get better results